# Opening SQL file from VS "Find Results" window opens the file twice in two instances of SSMS

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I've put up a screencast here to make the problem clearer: http://screencast.com/t/SZo8QGuQv

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2012 set as the default program for opening .sql files from Visual Studio 2013.

When I do a solution-wide search in Visual Studio that returns SQL files, opening any one of those results opens the file twice in two separate instances of SSMS.

This is a minor nuisance, but I've been dealing with it for years - across multiple computers and multiple versions of Windows, VS, and SSMS - and can't figure out what's causing it.

Comment: This appears to be some odd quirk with the interaction between VS and SSMS.  A workaround is to set the default editor for SQL files to the File Explorer (explorer.exe).  This will in turn open SSMS...a single instance however.

Comment: Sandra - I just tried this and the same exact thing happens (opens in two instances).

Comment: For what it's worth I just tried setting Notepad as the default for opening SQL files - and the same thing happens (same file opened in two instances of Notepad).

Answer (score 0):

Well

the window "Find result" have preview to select an item

When you selected one item VS it try do preview so double click raise two events

- preview
- open

the result is two instances of smss.

In the test to close smss it erase my sql file so use that trick [Visual Studio - Open a SQL file with SQL Management Studio in an existing SSMS window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193083/visual-studio-open-a-sql-file-with-sql-management-studio-in-an-existing-ssms-w) use explorer for open the file.

finally i could not do as your need but have one option

```
in "open with.." i set "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T_SQL Editor"
in "browse with.." i set "Windows Explorer"
```

after on contextual menu of Result added the option "Browse with"

here the context menu and the option "Browse With.."

[image]

and that is the result

[image]

the video preview http://www.screencast.com/t/MZFrUlvB4KYh

regards